# How do I use the AllowOverride directive to permit .htaccess files to override php_value (Apache2)

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I want to set the values of three different `php_value` parameters, on a per `<VirtualHost>` basis, using each hosts .htaccess file. Presumably in order to do this, I would need to place an `AllowOverride` directive within each `<VirtualHost>` configuration to permit the overriding of these values; I do not want to simply use `AllowOverride All` because that seems much too permissive and a bit overkill.

The problem seems to be that `php_value` is not an Apache2 directive, and nor are the names of specific values such as `memory_limit`, `max_upload_filesize` and `max_post_size`; however `AllowOverride` seems to only accept a subset of Apache2 directives as it's argument, as well as things like `All`, `Option`, etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm aware that I could simply use php.ini or include the `php_value` definitions within the `<VirtualHost>` configuration itself, but I'd really like to find out how it is done via the .htaccess file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the ["How to change configuration settings" documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php), `AllowOverride Options` is required to use the `php_value` directives. This is of course implicit in `AllowOverride All`. You do not use `php_value` as an argument to AllowOverride, `php_value` is a directive provided by mod_php, if you are not able to use it, you may not be running PHP as an Apache module. If so, so you will need to use [other methods of customizing the configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) on a per-site basis.

The configuration example in the the documentation is a good starting point. Step one is to verify that you are running mod_php. After that, provided you have set `AllowOverrides` appropriately for the virtual host, you should be able to simply add the `php_value` declarations to your .htaccess files. For instance, I just tested adding this line to a .htaccess file:

```
php_value arg_separator.input &|,
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I verified that `php7_module` is loaded and your solution worked fine. I'm not actually going to continue using the .htaccess file for this purpose but I'm glad I've discovered how it works!